# What is the difference between a distribution and a semi-distribution?

Tags: distributions, terminology

I hope the question to be clear.

The name "semi-distribution" certainly implies some meaning, yet, I'm unable to conclude what really means.

I found the term on this paper: http://www.info.ucl.ac.be/~pdupont/pdupont/pdf/pr05.pdf

**edit**

The definition given in the paper is:

> Let $\Sigma$ be a finite alphabet, a *semi-distribution* over $\Sigma^*$ is a function $\psi:\Sigma^*\to[0,1]$ satisfying $\sum_{u \in \Sigma^*} \psi(u)\le1$.

My guess is that it is a semi-distribution and not a distribution because the sum of the probability of all events is possibly less than 1.

Comment: People may not want to read the paper to understand & answer your question. Can you copy & paste the context in which the term is used?

Comment: @gung I just did.

Comment: Your guess is correct. The only difference between semi-distribution (there are similar terms such as sub-distribution etc.) and (true) distribution function is the former doesn't need to have total mass 1, while it maintains the non negative and non decreasing properties.

Comment: Excellent, thanks to both of you, Zhanxiong & gung.

Comment: They allow for nonzero probability of infinite words in their automata, which makes the distribution of finite words only a _semi-distribution_ (as they define it and you give above). I don't know whether this is a standard way to go about things, but it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between a distribution and a semi-distribution is that the sum of the probabilities of all the events don't need to add to 1 on a semi-distribution, they can add at most 1, possibly less. On a distribution, the total sum of probabilities has to add to 1, no more, no less.

@Zhanxiong pointed out that all the other properties of a distribution still apply (non negative and non decreasing properties).

Comment: Thanks.  But note that you simply reproduce the definition in the question.  Although I understand you are the one who asked it, how does this constitute a useful answer?

Comment: @whuber. By looking at the definition of a semi-distribution, is easy to see what it means; what is not so direct to understand is why it is called a semi-distribution. My answer points out the difference between a distribution and a semi-distribution, not only the definition of a semi-distribution. But if you don't think it may be useful for other users, I have no problem if you decide to delete the question (I already got the insight I was looking for)